# creating a subset of calculated fields based on count of unique values: python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a new df from my existing df. The new df is basically the count of unique values:
Example my original df is below (df) and I'm creating a new df called df_comp:

[image: original data]

And when I count their unique values as positive, negative and neutral using the below code, I get something like this:

df_comp = df.groupby(['company','review']).count()
print(df_comp[['review_id']])

[image: output]

but I require the positive, negative and neutral to be the columns of my new df, example:
[image: expected output]

Any suggestions pls, thank u

Answer (score 0):

Once you do your groupby(), you can use the `pivot_table` method.

```
df_pivot = df_comp.pivot_table(index=['company'], columns='review', values='review_id').reset_index()
```